# Adding Custom Fonts to a Web Page via Content Script in Chrome Extension Made with React and Webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, fonts

I am working on a project where I need to add custom fonts to a web page through a content script using React. The project is set up using Webpack.

I have tried importing the font files in my React component and using @font-face in the component's CSS file, but the fonts nor the extension loads. I'm pretty sure it's because it's not possible to use local assets.

I have also tried injecting a CSS file that includes @font-face into the web page using the content script, but that did not work either.

I came across a suggestion to add the fonts folder to the public folder and use the fonts via the URL
"chrome-extension://<extension_id>/fonts/some-font.tff"
However, I am not sure how to implement this solution in my React component or if it's the right approach.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My font",
    src: url("chrome-extension://\<extension_id\>/fonts/some-font.tff")
}
```

Can someone suggest a better approach to adding custom fonts to a web page through a content script? Or maybe it's not possible. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.